# Lightning server-side method returning "undefined"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

I have a very simple Lightning controller class that upserts a Contact record:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveContact(Contact newContact) {
    Contact c = newContact;
    upsert c;
    return c.Id;
}
```

The issue I am having is that although the upsert goes through just fine after calling from client's controller, the returned ID (String) from the server is coming back as "undefined".

Here's what the client controller's relative function looks like:

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    // grab component's new Contact holder attribute
    var con = component.get("v.newContact");

    // setup action
    var action = component.get("c.saveContact");
    action.setParams({ 
        "newContact" : con
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var conId = a.getReturnValue();
        console.log('Contact ID: '+ conId); // returns "undefined"
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

The Contact passed to *saveContact* is generated on the component, so it has all of its necessary field values before it reaches the server, where all that's left to do is the DML.

Can anyone see something that I might be missing here?  Can't understand why the returned ID value isn't coming through to the client.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the ID because it's probably erroring on upsert but you don't know that since you're not checking the state of the action.  Make your callback look like this:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    console.log('Was I successful? ' + a.getState()); // THIS IS NEW
    var conId = a.getReturnValue();
    console.log('Contact ID: '+ conId); // returns "undefined"
});
```

You should check if you're in a success or error callback:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Comment: Awesome catch, thank you James.  In doing this, I'm seeing that the event state is coming back "INCOMPLETE", which is odd.  Curious what could be causing a break in the communication.  I will add that this component is being used in an app on a VisualForce page using Lightning out.  Not sure if that is a possible explanation for this behavior or what.

Comment: I would say that this technically answers my question here, but if there is any further feedback out there on what could be causing the "INCOMPLETE" state, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a system.debug to check if newContact variable you are passing to server actually has any value. Looking at your code, thats the only breaking point.

Comment: Yes, I did try this before posting.  The debug log shows the passed Contact as expected, with all values intact.